# how to assign a block of html code to a javascript variable (to invoke a javascript call)

Tags: javascript, html

I want to assign a block of html code to a js variable

the html code is

```
<script>alert('test');</script>
```

I want to do this

```
var script = "<script>alert('test');</script>";

document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = script;
```

but it does not work

if I substitute the  tag (or any other tag) for the  tag, then it works.

```
var script = "<span>alert('test');</span>";
```

I tried

```
var script = "<script>alert('test');</script>";
eval(script);
```

and

```
eval ("<span>alert('test');</span>");
```

but they both have syntax errors.

It  probably has to do with have script tags inside of script tags

```
<script> <script> </script> </script>
```

Is there a way to get around this?

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot inject a `<script>` element using `.innerHTML` and expect it to evaluate.  You *must* use either `eval` or `document.write` or inject the `<script>` into the DOM the "normal" way.  With dynamic scripts, `eval` is recommended.

Remember that `eval` evaluates *pure JavaScript* and does not use the HTML interpreter.  (Contrast this with PHP's default behaviour, where `eval` is like inserting `?>$string<?php` into the document.)

Also remember that a script terminates when it approaches `</script>`.  It's strange to be inserting `</script>` into JavaScript anyway (unless you're using the `document.write` method, which has many problems and should be avoided where size isn't an extreme issue).

Here's an example of using `eval`:

```
var script = 'alert("test");';
eval(script);
```

If you want to inject a script into the DOM with other elements, you need to extract the `<script>` element after injecting and execute the (internal or external) script.  Frameworks like jQuery and Prototype do this automatically, which is one of the many reasons why they are recommended over vanilla JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

The way to do this with pure DOM methods I believe is as follows.

```
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.type = "text/javascript";
script.innerHTML = "alert('foo!')"; 
document.body.appendChild( script );
```

Works for me™.

Comment: I guess that's because IE has a broken DOM?